# Google Tag Manager (GTM) - "HTML" tag injection by client

Tags: google-tag-manager

We provide an ecommerce checkout on a subsection of our website for example:

> example.com/products,
> example.com/checkout,
> example.com/confirmation

For just those sections of our site we allow our client to add their own Google Tag Manager (GTM) tag.  We've blacklisted the "HTML" tag because it allows arbitrary javascript and can be updated at any point.

```
var dataLayer = [{ 'gtm.blacklist': ['html'] }];
```

The business/marketing departments want me to allow it now.  Is any safe way to allow the "HTML" tag that doesn't involve moving everything to a third party domain?

Answer (score 1):

There is no safe, or for that matter performant, way to use custom HTML tags or custom Javascript variables (the ones with the anonymous functions). Javascript code therein is run through eval, and can do anything that standard Javascript code can do (and given that the code runs in page context, it can basically do anything).

That is after all the reason Google created custom templates with Sandboxed Javascript that runs dangerous functions through secured APIs.

Do not allow this, and if they make you, keep a paper trail. Even if nobody will exploit this maliciously (which remains to be seen), somebody will sooner or later break the page by incompetence, so it is better to be covered.

Comment: Eike - I totally agree but I also understand marketing has their own job.  Was hoping there was some middle ground despite not knowing of one myself.  Thank you.

Comment: The middle ground is managed workflows - they pass you the scripts, you inspect the scripts, if they do nothing suspicious and do not load external assets outside your control you implement them. But letting people run their own JS on your site should be a big no. GTM360 has a built-in approval workflow, if you want to invest into that.

Comment: Also of course companies can supply their own custom templates - while they still can access everything from the datalayer, they cannot access the DOM, can only read cookies for which they have permission, cannot overload your JS method to do silly stuff etc.